# Angularjs table display

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have data fetched from json and displayed in a table. Im trying to display a header but when i use  it displays the data vertically and i want to display it horizontal

Here's my code

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="ninja in ninjass">
<th>
  {{ ninja.name }}
</th>
<td>
  {{ ninja.name }}
</td>
<td>
  {{ ninja.rate }}
</td>
<td>
  {{ ninja.rate }}
</td>
<td>
  {{ ninja.rate }}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <table>
        <th ng-repeat="ninja in ninjclass">
             {{ ninja.name }}
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="ninja in ninjclass">
                <td>{{ ninja.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ninja.rate }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Some explanation makes your answer better to understand

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The html for your table is wrong.  It should be of form:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>rate</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="ninja in ninjclass">
              <td>{{ninja.name}}</td>
              <td>{{ninja.rate}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: is it possible to not have static header?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="ninja in ninjass">
<th>
{{ ninja.name }}
</th>
</tr>

<tr>  <td>{{ ninja.name }}<td> </tr>

<tr>  <td>{{ ninja.name }}<td> </tr>

<tr>  <td>{{ ninja.rate }}<td> </tr>

<tr>  <td>{{ ninja.rate }}<td> </tr>

<tr>  <td>{{ ninja.rate }}<td> </tr>
</table>
```